# Dimensions for EV3pieces

Tags: piece-information, ev3, size

I need to know the dimensions of the EV3 pieces for a school project (in mm). Does anyone know?

Comment: Do you mean the LEGO technic bricks or the EV3 control brick and sensors? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I could only find the size of the servo motors:
Large servo motor: 14x7x5 modules -> 112x56x40 mm
Medium servo motor: 3x4x9 modules -> 24x32x72 mm

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any comprehensive parts dimension reference, but following should help you get started.
You can calculate part dimensions using fundamental dimensions of LEGO parts. The distance between holes in technic bricks is 8 mm (8 mm is one of core dimensions in whole LEGO).

So for example, lets take a beam (aka liftarm) with 7 holes, then length is 8mm*7=56 mm, and width is 8 mm.

Same rule for pegs, e.g. black pin with friction (used to connect 2 beams) has length of 8mm*2 = 16mm, diameter of 4.8mm - 6.2mm (depending on what part of pin you would measure).

LEGO technic axels follow same rule: their length is a multiple of 8.

You can read more on LEGO dimensions at  http://www.robertcailliau.eu/Lego/Dimensions/zMeasurements-en.xhtml